# Результат выполнения метода в реактивном потоке

Tags: java, spring-boot

Есть метод `uploadStop`, который выполняет `POST` запрос, а после того как он успешно выполнен нужно вызвать метод `createTask`.

```
public Mono<Task> createTask(Item item) {

    TaskParams taskParams = new TaskParams();

    Task task = new Task();
    task.setFrmoID(AppConstant.CODE_FRMO);

    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    String json = null;
    try {
        json = mapper.writeValueAsString(task);
    } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }

    String url = URL + "client/task";
    return webClient.post()
            .uri(url)
            .header(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, "Bearer " + cachedToken)
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .body(BodyInserters.fromValue(json))
            .retrieve()
            .bodyToMono(Task.class);
}

public Mono<String> uploadStop(String taskId) {
    String url = URL + "client/upload/stop";

    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    Map<String, String> jsonMap = new HashMap<>();
    jsonMap.put("task_id", taskId);

    String json = null;
    try {
        json = mapper.writeValueAsString(jsonMap);
    } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }

    return webClient.post()
            .uri(url)
            .header(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, "Bearer " + cachedToken)
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .body(BodyInserters.fromValue(json))
            .retrieve()
            .bodyToMono(String.class);
}
```

В результате выполнения запроса в методе `uploadStop` ничего не возвращается.

Сначала вызывается метод `uploadStop` если он успешно выполнен вызывается `createTask`. Пытаюсь реализовать так:

```
uploadStop(taskId)
    .flatMap(result -> createTask(dicomItem))
    .doOnNext(task -> System.out.println("Задача создана: " + task))
    .doOnError(error -> System.out.println("Ошибка: " + error))
    .subscribe();
```

Но почему-то ни один из выводов в консоль не срабатывает. Почему так?